# jQuery entire page flickering on certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ywq8G/

I wonder if someone is able to tell me: Why menu1 is flickering after clicking a submenu(the green one) the other two work just fine, but debugging is getting me nowhere and I was like: SO has given me so much answers allready(with just reading) may I contribute and ask my specific question.

I hope the solution will make me a better developer and help others avoid the problems I have encountered.

```
var MENU_HEIGHT = 110; 


$(document).ready(function () { 
    var menuCollection = {}
    var i = 1;
    $(".menu").children().each(function () {
        menuCollection[i] = [];
        $(".subMenu" + i).children().each(function () {
            menuCollection[i].push(this);
        });
        i++;
    });

    function scroll(menu, item, status) {
        if (item < menu.length) {
            var currentChild = menu[item];
            if (status == "scrollOut") {
                $(currentChild).stop().animate({
                    top: MENU_HEIGHT + 80 * item
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 600
                }) {
                    scroll(menu, item + 1, status);
                };
            } else {
                $(currentChild).stop().animate({
                    top: 0
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 600
                }) {
                    scroll(menu, item + 1, status);
                };
            }
        }
    }
    var ii = 1;
    $(".menu").children().each(function () {
        var target = $(this).attr('class');
        var menu = menuCollection[ii];

        $("." + target + ", .subMenu" + ii + " > a").bind("mouseover", function () {
            doScroll(menu, 0, "scrollOut");
        });
        $("." + target + ", .subMenu" + ii + " > a").bind("mouseout", function () {
            doScroll(menu, 0, "scrollIn");
        });
        ii++;
    });


    function doScroll(menu, item, status) {
        scroll(menu, item, status);
    }

    $("a").click(function (event) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.substring(1);

        $(".current").appendTo(".hidden");
        $(".current").removeClass("current");


        $("." + href).addClass("current");
        $("." + href).appendTo(".main");

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".main").offset().top
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any flickering when I mouse over the menu. It seems to work just like the others.

Comment: it flickers when you click on a certain item

Comment: @just the same like Pointy said. Additionally I would suggest you to use a timeout by hovering your menu elements (like a Hover Intent). If one is a bit slower the FX by hovering different tabs is wuite ugly

Comment: but then the strange thing is that the other menu;s (menu2, menu3) work just fine, no matter how many times i try. But yes using a timeout is indeed a good call, but I dont think it will solve my problem.

Comment: Try adding `event.preventDefault()` before returning from your anchor click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is flickering because you are using href parameter of  tag with '#' and when you click on it browsers move window to element with id like #-value. And if you have a lot of content to change browsers first jump to this id and next use your  $('html, body').animate({...}) function (so again jump to top and animate to down).

You can change 'href' for example to 'myHref' (in html and js) it's should resolve the problem.

(sorry for my english, i hope is understandable)

Comment: but Mateusz how you explain why this bug only occur on the green menu and not on the other 2? They both use the same parameter. But thanks for the answer, I'll give it a go!

Comment: because in the green menu you have for example '<a href="#mne_features">(...)</a>' element and you have a '<div (...) id="mne_features">Features</div>' element, so when you click on this <a> element browser go to the this <div> element. But in blue and orange menu you have a '<a>' element with ' href="#(...)" ' but you don't have any element with the same id parameter, so browsers do nothing.

Comment: excellent mateusz, now i see what you mean ! i voted yours for the right answer, thank you very much!